# SPOJ retorna "Resposta errada" para solução aparentemente correta

Tags: c++

Tentei resolver o problema [BANCO12 - Banco](http://br.spoj.com/problems/BANCO12/) do SPOJ, mas, ao submeter meu código C++, o sistema retorna "resposta errada". Segue meu código: `

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nc, np, i, c, livre=0, cont=0;
    cin>>nc>>np;
    int caixa[nc], espera[np], chegada, demora;

    for(i=0; i<nc; i++){
        caixa[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<np; i++){
        cin>>chegada>>demora;
        espera[i] = caixa[livre]-chegada;
        if(espera[i]>20){cont++;}
        caixa[livre]+=demora;

        if(nc>1){
            for(c=0; c<nc; c++){
                if(caixa[livre]>caixa[c]){
                    livre = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<cont<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Não sei onde está o erro, será que podem me ajudar?

Comment: retire a linha `cout<<espera[i]<<endl;`, seu codigo tem varias saidas e o site requer apenas o resultado.

Comment: Desculpe, eu utilizei isso para fazer um teste mas esqueci de retirar, mesmo sem essa linha esta dando erro. Ainda assim obrigado!

Comment: pode ser a quebra de linha da resposta, tenta usar apenas `cout << cont;`

Comment: Não, estava faltando um caso de teste, quando a chegada é maior que o caixa livre, consegui resolver. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, o código não estava considerando o caso em que a chegada é maior que o caixa livre. Então era só adicionar essa linha de código: `if(chegada>caixa[livre]){caixa[livre]=chegada;}`, antes de calcular a espera. O código  final fica dessa forma:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nc, np, i, c, livre=0, cont=0;
    cin>>nc>>np;
    int caixa[nc], espera[np], chegada, demora;

    for(i=0; i<nc; i++){
        caixa[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<np; i++){
        cin>>chegada>>demora;
        if(chegada>caixa[livre]){caixa[livre]=chegada;}
        espera[i] = caixa[livre]-chegada;
        if(espera[i]>20){cont++;}
        caixa[livre]+=demora;

        if(nc>1){
            for(c=0; c<nc; c++){
                if(caixa[livre]>caixa[c]){
                    livre = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<cont<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```